AHKv2 Unable to offset excel value with ComObjGet - 'Error: This value of type "String" has no method named "Offset".'
AUTOHOTKEY v2.0.18
I have 2 codes. One works flawlessly and the other, which is almost exactly the same, does not.
Can you identify where I'm going wrong here please?
WORKING - TEST CODE TO GET IT TO WORK
wbPath := A_Desktop "\Test File AHK.xlsx"
xl := ComObjGet(wbPath)

^+F1::
{
xl.Sheets(1).Range("A:A").Find(3).Offset(0,3).Value := ComObjActive("Excel.Application").ActiveCell.Value ; Works
}

NOT WORKING - ACTUAL CODE I WANT TO USE
wbPath := A_Desktop "\INVOICING SHEET.xlsx"
xl := ComObjGet(wbPath)

!+x::
{
title := WinGetTitle("A") ; Works
UniqueRef := Trim(SubStr(title,1,InStr(title," (")-1)) ; Works

msgbox ComObjActive("Excel.Application").ActiveCell.Value ; Works
xl.Sheets(1).Range("A:A").Find(UniqueRef).Offset(0,11).Value := ComObjActive("Excel.Application").ActiveCell.Value
}

Context: My goal is to retrieve the unique ref in the title of my current doc (works), lookup the location in an external sheet and input the value of ActiveCell in the sheet I'm working from.
In code 2, the ActiveCell portion works but it just won't let me use offset even though it's fine in Code 1. This line in particular:
xl.Sheets(1).Range("A:A").Find(UniqueRef).Offset(0,11).Value

Error:

All paths are checked and correct. There are no issues with my excel sheets or Office version (full, paid version - Office 2021).
Any help is greatly appreciated!

The problem appears if nothing is found by xl.Sheets(1).Range("A:A").Find(UniqueRef).
Typically, it should be done by this way:
MyVar := xl.Sheets(1).Range("A:A").Find(UniqueRef)
If (MyVar<>)
    MyVar.Offset(0,11).Value := ComObjActive("Excel.Application").ActiveCell.Value


Thank you very much for the response rotabor, unfortunately it's not VBA I'm using in this instance, this is an AutoHotkey script https://www.autohotkey.com/

Thank you so much for your effort on this! After some debugging and inspiration from your answer, I discovered that the find did indeed return null. I adjusted my offset and specified the sheet to resolve this. I tried your code but it failed @ "(MyVar<>)" so I replaced this with Try & Catch Error. I have posted my answer. Thank you for your efforts and I hope you enjoy AHK!

I was offsetting by 1 column too much. In addition, Sheets(1) does not refer to Sheet1 in excel, I have no specified the sheet name. The error is given when nothing can be found, I prevented this with a Try & Catch Error combo. Working code:
^+F1::
{
Try {

title := WinGetTitle("A") ; Works
UniqueRef := Trim(SubStr(title,1,InStr(title," (")-1)) ; Works

xl.Sheets("CURRENT").Range("A:A").Find(UniqueRef).Offset(0,10).Value := ComObjActive("Excel.Application").ActiveCell.Value ;WORKS!
} Catch Error {

    msgbox "Unable to locate reference.","Error."

}
Return
}

